# SSO based on email address in a refreshed sandbox

Tags: single-sign-on, mydomain

We've set up SSO through My Domain and it matches user email. So when they attempt to log in through My Domain, as long as their SSO email match the SF email - they're in.

If I check "prevent login from salesforce.com" in production - I'm anticipating an issue if we refresh with the box still checked.

Assuming "prevent login from test.salesforce.com" will be checked after a refresh in the sandbox and an ".invalid" is appended to the end of emails which will cause an issue when logging in.

Any ideas for a work around (other than unchecking "prevent login from salesforce.com" before a refresh and checking it again once the refresh is complete)?

Comment: Use Federation ID.

Comment: Use Federation Id and leave some users without SSO so they can update the SSO setting to point to the myDomain of the sandbox

Comment: Usually the user who initiates the refresh is not marked as .invalid. if you are concerned then you can write a post refresh script .